# How to get all blue background divs to align to the left and get all the red divs to align to the right using the css float property?

Tags: css

Can someone kindly help me lineup all blue divs to the left side and have all the red divs float to the left using the float property. The picture below should explain the goal of this question. Thanks in advance.

For example,

```
                  -------------            --------------- 
                  |  left Top |            |  right Top  |
                  -------------            ---------------

                  ---------------          ----------------
                  | left Middle |          | right Middle |
                  ---------------          ----------------

                  ---------------------    ----------------------
                  |     left Bottom   |    |     right Bottom   |
                  ---------------------    ----------------------
```

Here's the css and html code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org   /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Through the Looking-Glass</title>
 <style>

 #container
 {
height: 798px;
width: 1300px;
    margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
    background-color: black;
 }

 #leftTop 
 {
   background-color: blue;
   width: 200px;
   float: left;
   height: 40px;
   color: white;
 }

 #rightTop
 {
   background-color: red;
   width: 200px;
   height: 40px;
   float: left;
   clear: right;
   color: white;
 }
   #leftMiddle
 {
   background-color: blue;
   width: 600px;
   height: 40px;
   float: left;
   clear: right; 
   top: 10px;
   color: white;
   border: 1px solid white;
 }
 #rightMiddle
 {
   background-color: red;
   width: 600px;
   float: left;
   height: 40px;
   margin-top: 10px;
   color: white;
 }
 #leftBottom
 {
   background-color: blue;
   width: 600px;
   float: left;
   height: 400px;
   color: white;
 }
 #rightBottom
 {
   background-color: red;
   width: 600px;
   float: left;
   height: 400px;
   color: white;
 }
 </style>

 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="container">
                    <div id="leftTop"> Left Top</div>
                <div id="rightTop"> Right Top</div>
                        <div id="leftMiddle"> Left Middle</div>
                <div id="rightMiddle"> Right Middle</div>
                        <div id="leftBottom"> Left Bottom </div>
                        <div id="rightBottom"> Right Bottom </div>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create 2 column `<div>` elements to wrap the left column `<div>`s and the right column `<div>`s.

Comment: Thanks Lucas, is there a solution using the float property?

Comment: A table would work just fine too... and a table would be easier to handle I think.  Less css required.

Comment: @bozdoz, He did explicitly ask for float.  And trying to stay in line with HTML 5, you should only use `<table>` for tabular data, not as a layout mechanism.

Comment: @YetimworkBeyene, If this answer is sufficient, mark it as the answer, or you could post a more thorough answer of your own and mark that as the answer.

Comment: thanks Lucas, I was able to getting working with your answer.